# How to prevent navbar hiding when keyboard appears ios?

Tags: swift, uiwebview, navbar

I have an app which has a webview on a storyboard, which loads a registration form in ASP, so when the keyboard or a picker appears, the navbar hides, but never comes back, so I'm not able to go back to the last page.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class BannerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var webView11: UIWebView!

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle  {
        return .default
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool  {
        return false
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(false, animated: true)
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()


        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.38, blue: 0.667, alpha: 1)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        var titleTextAttributes = [String : AnyObject]();
        titleTextAttributes[NSFontAttributeName] = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17, weight: UIFontWeightSemibold)
        titleTextAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleTextAttributes
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
        self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

        self.webView11.delegate = self;
        if let unwrappedwebView11 = URL(string: "http://www.stackoverflow") {
            self.webView11.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: unwrappedwebView11))
        }
    }



}


extension BannerViewController: UIWebViewDelegate {



}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like i need to refresh the view or something, as i added a back button out of the webView and when i click and go back to last view, and then i got in again to the webView the navBar doesn´t move anymore